# HTML Injection Windows RT WebView

Tags: javascript, html, webview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i'am trying to insert values to a HTML Document on my Windows Universal App, the HTML Document is located on a Webserver and I'am trying  to insert username and password saved on the client device Winphone or PC Store App, I know the id and every thing about the elemts, but I cant figure out how to insert a string into an input value, can someone provied a sample with InvokeScript("smth", new string[] {smthelse});

or has someone a better idea to insert username and password from into the HTML content of a webview?

I'am stuck here and I realy need this feature.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your XAML and give it a go.  If you know the ID, you can set its value by doing some script injection into the page.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerText = 'Hello, {0}';", nameTextBox.Text);
    await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```

Don't be naughty.  Healy in Tampa.